# Value Error with Float/Integer/double Fields in Python?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, arcpy

When running this Code:

```
import arcpy 
from arcpy import env
import os

#Specify the map document and the data frame
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"G:\\PythonCode\\mxd_test.mxd")
env.workspace = r"G:\\LoopTest.gdb"
#output file folder
outPath = r"G:\Mxd_MapAutomation\\Test4\\"

FCs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

# loop through all Featurecalsses in env.workspace
for FCLASS in FCs:

    #Skip all Text. OID and Geometry Fields - unfortunately WID, Shape Area etv is still included
    AllFields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(FCLASS)]
    LeaveOutField = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(FCLASS,field_type='String')]
    LeaveOutField.extend([f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(FCLASS,field_type='Geometry')])
    LeaveOutField.extend([f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(FCLASS,field_type='OID')])
    attrlist = [x for x in AllFields if x not in LeaveOutField]

    # layer which has to change the attribute field
    flayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*")
    featurelayer = flayer[7]

    # text element that has to change (e.g. title...)
    title = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "map_title")[0]
    for attr in attrlist:

        # change value field
        featurelayer.symbology.valueField = attr

        # change tilte
        title.text = attr

        # update view
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
        arcpy.RefreshTOC()

        # export as jpeg
        outJPEG = os.path.join(outPath, FCLASS + "_" + attr + ".jpg")
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, outJPEG, "PAGE_LAYOUT", 200, 200, 300, False, "24-BIT_TRUE_COLOR", 90, False)

del mxd
```

I get following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/DDP_loop_Code.py", line 35, in <module>
    featurelayer.symbology.valueField = attr
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\_base.py", line 87, in _set
    return setattr(self._arc_object, attr_name, cval(val))
ValueError: hhfishing
```

and I have no idea why.. the code basically runs through all FC in the GDB. It does it correctly with the first FeatureClass and stops with the error in the second Feature Class. Even if I would put in other Feature Classes the Error would appear in the same way. All the fields are either float or integer and the field where the error appears is not different to any other field where the code works on..

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error?

Comment: What's the precise error message and line number in relation to the code snippet that you have provided?  Please **edit** it into your question.

Comment: It seems to me that your layer probably has a UniqueValuesRenderer so setting a field other than int (long/short) into the .valueField is going to cause pain.. is this correct? Without the *exact* error message (like @PolyGeo said) I can't be certain; the information contained in the wording is important so it needs to be a verbatim copy. The only way to get around this is to ensure that *every* layer has an integer symbology field... is the field you're trying to use the same name for every feature class? or is it always the -5th element like you have?

Comment: The error that you have included is only part of what I was expecting, and unfortunately the least useful part.  Can you please try running your code from an IDE like IDLE and provide us with the whole error - in particular the bit that tells us the line number of your script and what it was executing when it errored.

Comment: It is actually much more informative which has enabled me to start to answer your question, and to see if that question can start to become more focussed.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson It seems like it is always the 6th field in all FeatureClasses..(the fields in all FC on that position have different names and types though) except from the first FC where it runs ok..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the test code below using ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:\\temp\\temp.mxd")
featurelayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Animals_Insects")[0]
attr = 'hhsericiculture'
featurelayer.symbology.valueField = attr
print "Works for field hhsericiculture"
attr = 'pct_ahhwinsect_raising'
featurelayer.symbology.valueField = attr
print "Gets error before getting here"
```

I saw the first print statement appear, as expected, but I also saw the second which means that the error you describe was not encountered on the line before.

These are my field definitions:

- `hhsericiculture`

[image]

- `pct_ahhwinsect_raising`

[image]

and my symbology settings for the layer:

[image]

I think you should double-check whether I am running an identical test to yours.  If so, perhaps this is  a version difference between your 10.1 and my 10.3.1.

As an afterthought I wonder whether your field has any null values in it - I know that mine does not - and it might explain why you are getting a ValueError rather than another type of error.

Comment: I updated my question, still couldn't figure out the error.

Comment: I suspect that there are null values in your `hhfishing` field now.

Comment: there are but they need to be <null>.. is this process not possible with null-values?

Comment: You should be able to apply a definition query to your layer to leave just those which are non null.

Comment: do I do this with _if foo is None:_ ? or is it more a code like this? _http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90736/how-to-set-definition-query-on-arcpy-layer-from-shapefile_ ?

Comment: I think it should be more like in that link.  However, I think your original question has been answered already so really this would be better investigated in a separate Q&A with a different code snippet and data description that we could use to test/reproduce and work around.