# ValueError when setting symbology.valueField on a layer after a join

Tags: arcpy, symbology, valueerror

I know a similar question has been asked [elsewhere](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150545/value-error-with-float-integer-double-fields-in-python/150559#150559), but I'm not sure whether the problem I'm having relates to the fact that I'm trying to apply symbology to a layer after a join, or that I'm trying to import it from an external file. Anyway, the section of code looks like this:

```
arcpy.AddJoin_management(bLyr, "ONSCD", engIMD, "utlacd13", 'KEEP_ALL') 
    arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(bLyr, "C:\\My Documents\\ArcGISmaps\\postJoin.lyr",\
                                                                         "ABSOLUTE") 
    postJoin = arcpy.mapping.Layer("C:\\My Documents\\ArcGISmaps\\postJoin.lyr")
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(eng, postJoin, "TOP")

arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(postJoin, os.path.join(outputDir, "symbENG.lyr"))
# ^ this is a layer I defined and saved outside this map file, to
# basically be a template for the symbology

if postJoin.symbologyType == "GRADUATED_COLORS":
    print postJoin.symbologyType
    attr = 'avscor_utla'
   #Now according to IDLE, the error occurs at this next line:
    postJoin.symbology.valueField = attr
    postJoin.symbology.addAllValues()
    postJoin.symbology.numClasses = 5
else:
    print postJoin.symbologyType
```

The error I receive is

```
ValueError: avscor_utla
```

`avscor_utla` is the same field used in `symbENG.lyr` where I define the symbology. In both cases, the values for this field are Doubles, and I've checked to make sure there are no null values.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing the name of the attribute you are using for the symbology, adding the table name as a prefix. If that attribute is in your engIMD table, the attribute name should be `engIMD.avscor_utla`, and not just `avscor_utla`.